# Android Room - Customize query to return certain value based on a condition

Tags: android, sql, android-room

For the sake of this scenario I have a `user` table and two tables where each `user` can be of one or two types, `friend` and `family` tables respectively. These two only contain the ids if the users stored in the `user` table.

I am trying to do the following:

Return all users that are `friends` *or* `family`, ordered by name and grouped by `type`.

So far I've had almost no trouble, the problem comes up when I want to group by `type` inside the query and add separators in the `RecyclerView` to distinguish a user that is a friend and a user that is family.

My intention is to add some sort of boolean value in the query itself to serve as a flag and thus distinguish the users that are being returned in the same list, but I am having immense difficulty in finding any sort of guidance or examples on how to do this.

This is an example (non-working) of what I am trying to do:

```
@Query("" +
    "SELECT " +
    "*, " +
    "table source? as type " + // here
    "FROM UserFamily " +
    "LEFT JOIN User " +
    "ON UserFamily.id = User.id " +
    "LEFT JOIN UserFriend " +
    "ON User.status = UserFriend.id " +
    "ORDER BY name ASC " +
    "GROUP BY ... table source? " // here
)
```

How can this be achieved? I understand I could just add all the different types as columns in the user table and boolean each one, but this is not an option.

EDIT: Sample data as requested

`User` table

```
| id | first_name | age |
|:--:|:----------:|:---:|
|  1 |    Danny   |  28 |
|  2 |    Susan   |  15 |
|  3 |    Lenny   |  45 |
```

`Friend` table (id is a foreign key belonging to `User` table)

```
| id |
|:--:|
|  3 |
```

`Family` table (id is a foreign key belonging to `User` table)

```
| id |
|:--:|
|  1 |
```

Desired results:

```
| id | first_name | age | type |
|:--:|:----------:|:---:|:----:|
|  1 |    Danny   |  28 |   1  |
|  3 |    Lenny   |  45 |   2  |
```

Where `type` would represent a user that is family or friend by 1 and 2, sorted by `first_name` and grouped by `type`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am afraid I don't understand what you are asking for, so I did my best to try and accommodate your request in my edit note in the answer, let me know if you meant something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is use field `type` like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN UserFamily.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 // type = 1 means it's a family
  WHEN UserFriend.id IS NOT NULL THEN 2 // type = 2 means it's a friend
else 0 // type = 0 means it's neither family not friend
END as type
```

Comment: I had no idea Room allowed CASE ... END to be used like this - granted I'm very green in SQL still. I will try this one and see how it goes.